# Overlapping Tiles

Tags: geometry

Suppose you had two stained-glass tiles in the shapes of polygons and you laid them on top of each other. Their overlapping area also forms a polygon, like the ones I have shown in the image:
[image]

Notice how the blue squares overlap to form a triangle, the green triangles overlap to form a quadrilateral, and the orange polygons overlap to form two disjoint polygons: a triangle and a quadrilateral. Here is your challenge:

1. Overlap a triangle and a square to form a septagon.
2. Overlap a triangle and a quadrilateral to form an octagon.
3. Overlap two quadrilaterals to form two disjoint polygons: one septagon, and one quadrilateral.
4. Overlap two quadrilaterals to form a decagon.
5. Overlap two hexagons to form a 16-gon.

Remember that the polygons need not always be convex!

Comment: Can I politely suggest that you don't post as many puzzles in such a short amount of time? They will get less attention and people prefer to look at one puzzle at a time

Comment: Fair enough. I was just going through all of my old notebooks and I found a bunch of old ones that I made. Should I delete some of them and save them for later?

Comment: Don't delete them now, but just hold back in the future. They still look like good puzzles, but I can't look at them all at once :)

Comment: Okay, sorry about that.

Comment: @Frpzzd I like them all, Thanks for sharing this pretty good question. need to sleep now, if noone solves the last one, I will do it :)

Comment: @Rubio Right, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. > [image]
2. > [image]
3. > [image]
4. > [image]
5. by **[Boboquack](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30903/boboquack)**

> [image]

Here are the solution for all shapes!

Comment: I've cleaned up 5

Answer (score 4):

And the answer to part 5 (sorry Oray):

> [image: 16-gon]

With congruent polygons:

> [image: Another 16-gon]

Comment: Wow... that looks really messy, but you did it! Good job!

Comment: @Frpzzd Cleaned up now

Comment: ... now can you do it with two congruent polygons?

Comment: @Frpzzd You should probably ask that as a separate question

Comment: Nah, it's not *that* hard...

Comment: @Frpzzd Okay...